# What drives the redox reactions in a standard hydrogen electrode?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_vR0Eqb5gY), the SHE half cell has two redox reactions occurring i.e.

$$\ce{2H+ (g) + 2e- <=> H2 (g)}\\
\ce{H2 (g) <=> 2H+ (g) + 2e-}$$

But how can a single half cell initiate the two reactions? In the video, e<sup>-</sup> are going into the platinum wire which react with the H<sup>+</sup> in the aqueous solution, but where does the e<sup>-</sup> come from?

And how can $\ce{H2 (g)}$ randomly release two $\ce{e-}$ into the copper wire? Where did the $\ce{H2 (g)}$ get the energy to release the two $\ce{e-}$?

Comment: The short answer is that it doesn't. You need something (an oxidant) to pick up the electrons in such a way that the overall process of transferring electrons is favorable. Also, only the first reaction you wrote is a reduction. The other is an oxidation.

Answer (score 0):

It is an equilibrium reaction, so the two reactions occur at the same rate and the net current is 0 (electrons are flowing in both directions). A net current will flow only if another half cell is connected.